# How to link preexisting fundraising pages to 'contributions' when setting up CiviCRM

Tags: contributions, evaluating-civicrm

My NGO is thinking about setting up CiviCRM primarily to coordinate donations but we're totally new to all of this. We have various preexisting fundraising pages and profiles on other websites through which people can donate. Is it possible to link all of these diverse sources through to the CiviCRM Contributions section so they're coordinated? How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of using CiviCRM is to create contribution pages within CiviCRM for displaying on your website to collect donations.

You **may** be able to do what you want using the API, but that would need definitely need to be set up by a developer. (I am not a developer hence the "may".)

Comment: Thanks! And what is the mechanism by which payment is received then? Do you plug in bank details on the back end and it all happens through CiviCRM? Or would it be possible to reroute from the CiviCRM contribution page through to 3rd party websites which we already have set up to receive donations?

Answer (score 0):

If you can replace any links pointing to those 'other' systems and send everyone to the Contribution page as explained by JoAnne